# Building a json tree structure from identifiers

Tags: python, json, tree, identifier

I have a file with data that looks like that :

```
ID attribute
1 'text'
101 'text'
1011 'text'
10111 'text'
1011101 'text'
1011102 'text'
1011103 'text'
1011104 'text'
1011130 'text'
```

My goal is to build json tree structure from these data :

```
{
    [
    ID : 1,
    attribute : 'text',
    children : [
        ID: 101,
        attribute : 'text',
        children : [
             ...
    ID : 2,
        ...
    ]
}
```

In python, i builded a list of dictionnaries like that :

```
[ {'id': ID, 'attr' : text}, {...} ]
```

I think i could use the fact that leaf id contain his parents id but i can't see the way to build the structure i want.

I would appreciate any help, in pseudo code or any other programming langage.

Comment: I think you'd run into trouble, with that format anyway, if there's more that 99 top level trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from thg435 worked with little changes :

```
# open & read raw file
f=open(args[0], 'r')
text = f.read()

#
text = map(lambda s: s.split(" ", 1), text.strip().replace("'","").splitlines())
tree = [{'prefix': '', 'children':[]}]
stack = [tree[0]]

for id, attr in text:
    while not id.startswith(stack[-1]['prefix']):
        stack.pop()
    node = {'prefix': id, 'attr': attr, 'children': []}
    stack[-1]['children'].append(node)
    stack.append(node)

pprint.pprint( tree)

print json.dumps( tree)
f=open(args[1], 'w')
f.write(json.dumps( tree, sort_keys=True, indent=1))
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

I didn't quite get your ID numbering system, so here's code for a simple prefix tree:

```
ls = """
1 'text'
101 'text'
1011 'text'
10111 'text'
1011101 'text'
2 two
2111 'text'
21114 'text'
25 'text'
2567 'text'
"""
ls = map(str.split, ls.strip().splitlines())


tree = [{'prefix': '', 'children':[]}]
stack = [tree[0]]

for id, attr in ls:
    while not id.startswith(stack[-1]['prefix']):
        stack.pop()
    node = {'prefix': id, 'attr': attr, 'children': []}
    stack[-1]['children'].append(node)
    stack.append(node)

import pprint
pprint.pprint( tree)
```